# In Wordpress AJAX call for a PHP File that is getting data from Database and returning to Index file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I created a Code Base on PHP, Jquery and Ajax that is a changing dropdowns on change options. There are three parts of this program.

**First Part**
The first part of the file is a form having 3-input fields, these fields are getting option data from database and on changing option the values in the next input fields are filtered.

```
<?php  /**  * Plugin Name: My Car Plugin  */
    add_action(the_content, my_car_plugin);     ?>

<?php
    function register_script() {

        wp_enqueue_script('my_car_script', 'http://www.thenewsol.com/zaman/my_car_script.js', 'jQuery', '1.5.2');
        }
    function print_script() {
        wp_print_scripts('my_car_script');
        }
?> 


<?php 
    function my_car_plugin() { 
            register_script();
                print_script();
    ?>
        <div style="width:800px; margin:auto;padding-top:100px;">
            <form>
                <select id="Make" onchange="load_options(this.value,'Model');">
                    <option value="">- Select Make -</option>
                        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <select id="Model" onchange="load_options(this.value,'Year');">
                    <option value="">- Select Model -</option>
                </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <select id="Year">
                <option value="">- Select Year -</option>
                    </select>
                        <img src="loader.gif" id="loading" align="absmiddle" style="display:none;"/>
    <?php 
                            }
        ?>
```

**Second Part**
This part is a jQuery Function that is calling the third part of the the program through Ajax call.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
load_options('','Make');
});

function load_options(id,index){
jQuery("#loading").show();
    if(index=="Model"){
        jQuery("#Year").html('<option value="">- Select Year -</option>');
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
            complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
                success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#"+index).html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

**Third Parat**
The third and the last part of the program is a file that is interacting with database and providing data for first part of the program on Ajax Call.

```
<?php

class AJAX {


    public  $_index = NULL;



    public function __construct(){

        $this->process_data();
    }


private function process_data(){

global $wpdb; // Wordpress Global Database Variable access

    $this->_index = ($_REQUEST['index'])?$_REQUEST['index']:NULL;
        $id = ($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']:NULL;
switch($this->_index){

    case 'Make':
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_countries");
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($results as $rows){

        echo "<option value=\"$rows->id\">".$rows->country_name."</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        break;

    case 'Model':
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_states WHERE country_id=$id");
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($results as $rows){

        echo "<option value=\"$rows->id\">$rows->state_name</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        break;

    case 'Year':
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_cities WHERE state_id=$id");
        echo "<select>";
        foreach($results as $rows){

        echo "<option value=\"$rows->id\">$rows->city_name</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        break;

    default:
        break;

}

    }


}

$obj = new AJAX();

?>
```

**Requirements**
I tried to convert this program in the form of Wordpress Plugin. I could not figure it out that where is the actual problem in this code. Why it is not working?
If I remove the wordpress formats and run it on localhost its working perfectly. But when I try to embed in wordpress its not working.

**Please do guide / help in resolving this issue.**

---

Thanks for your guidance. Actually, I'm not good in using AJAX. Will you please elaborate how I can change my jQuery / Ajax functin in Wordpress. My function is this

```
    jQuery.ajax({ url: "ajax.php?index="+index+"&id="+id,
      complete: function(){$("#loading").hide();},
       success: function(data) {
     jQuery("#"+index).html(data); } })
```

Your code is this one

```
jQuery.post(
 ajax_object.ajax_url,
  data, function(response) {
   alert('Got this from the server: ' + response); });
```

*Please convert/ change my code in that format*

Comment: add some code checking options, see what files run, until where they run... is the first jqury loaded throwe wp_enqueue_script?

Comment: You are doing the Plugin and the Ajax *very* **very wrong**. It's impossible to fix this. Research here and at [wordpress.se] for working examples and rebuild your thing.

Comment: Belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.