# Get WordPress variables in AJAX PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, global-variables

I've written a form and trying to send the data via AJAX to my own PHP script within the theme folder. There are different kinds of operations within this file.

Everything works fine, but now I need to access some variables (e.g. `bloginfo('url')`) and trying to write them in an email for example.

#### How can I access the WordPress variables in an 'external' PHP script?

Thanks for help.

---

Note: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395635/in-wordpress-ajax-call-for-a-php-file-that-is-getting-data-from-database-and-ret) before, but for me it's not possible to include the code in the functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your own PHP script, add `require( '/path/to/your/root/wp-load.php' );` to load WordPress.

Comment: It works - Thank you very much, couldn't find that little hint anywhere :)